# Why is nmap that slow on my system (ubuntu 14.04)?

Tags: virtualization, ports, nmap

I just started to learn something about portscanning with nmap. when i try to run an a nullscan or any other type on a virtual machine (win7 no firewall) the scan needs a lot of time to perform:

```
sebi@sebi-UX31A:~$ sudo nmap -sN 192.168.1.109

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-01-01 22:07 CET
Nmap scan report for win7-PC (192.168.1.109)
Host is up (0.00054s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on win7-PC (192.168.1.109) are closed
MAC Address: 08:00:27:4D:CF:E8 (Cadmus Computer Systems)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 45.53 seconds
```

Unfortunately I have no idea how to solve the problem. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Are you are running a virtual machine inside a Win7 host? I think the issue here is the half-open tcp connection limit which derives from host os. As it seems that 1000 ports / 45 sec ~ 22 ports/sec which is pretty close to half-open connection limit of 20 in Windows. You could try to run a different kind of scan to verify this.. like a UDP scan as it's not affected by this limit.

Comment: no i am running ubuntu 14.04. the vm is win7. the udp scan needs several minutes. i canceled the scan after 8 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You're running `nmap` at its default scan speed, which should take about 90 seconds to scan a local system.  If you want to scan faster, specify either `-T4` or `-T5` as the scanning speed.  Note that a faster speed can be less accurate if either the connection or the computer at the other end can't handle it, and is more likely to trigger firewalls or IDSs.